# Which class contains the logic for invoking action method in APPLY REQUEST VALUES phase when command button is set with the immedaite=true?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

i am going through the sources of Mojarra JSF-impl 2.1.19 to know internals. but i am not able to find the logic for invoking action method in APPLY REQUEST VALUES phase(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute method... and the methods called inside that) itself **when command button is set with the attribute immedaite=true**. could any one help me to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the renderer which does the decoding and action event queueing job. In case of specifically Mojarra's implementation of `<h:commandButton>`, it's the [`ButtonRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/ButtonRenderer.java#ButtonRenderer). Here's an extract of relevance from its [`decode()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/ButtonRenderer.java#ButtonRenderer.decode%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,javax.faces.component.UIComponent%29) method:

```
77     public void decode(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) {
78 
79         rendererParamsNotNull(context, component);
80 
81         if (!shouldDecode(component)) {
82             return;
83         }
84 
85         String clientId = decodeBehaviors(context, component);
86 
87         if (wasClicked(context, component, clientId) && !isReset(component)) {
88             component.queueEvent(new ActionEvent(component));
89 
..             
97         }
98 
99     }
```

See, it delegates further to the component's own `queueEvent()` method. The component class of the `<h:commandButton>` is the [`HtmlCommandButton`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandButton.java#HtmlCommandButton) which extends from [`UICommand`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/javax/faces/component/UICommand.java#UICommand). Its [`queueEvent()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.1.19/javax/faces/component/UICommand.java#UICommand.queueEvent%28javax.faces.event.FacesEvent%29) method is in turn implemented as follows:

```
335    public void queueEvent(FacesEvent e) {
336        UIComponent c = e.getComponent();
337        if (e instanceof ActionEvent && c instanceof ActionSource) {
338            if (((ActionSource) c).isImmediate()) {
339                e.setPhaseId(PhaseId.APPLY_REQUEST_VALUES);
340            } else {
341                e.setPhaseId(PhaseId.INVOKE_APPLICATION);
342            }
343        }
344        super.queueEvent(e);
345    }
```

See? The target phase of executing the action event is determined and set over there based on component's `immediate` attribute.